# Widget.Material3 TextAppearance attribute Error

Tags: android, xml, material-design, uiappearance, app-themes

#### While using this style from material styles, It doesn't matter where I provide the TextAppearance in my AppTheme or extend that style itself and provide TextAppearance

The app crashes with the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This component requires that you specify a valid TextAppearance attribute. Update your app theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
> at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTextAppearance(ThemeEnforcement.java:185)
> at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:116)
> at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:474)
> at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:433)

The XML component looks like below

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/txtcountry"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:hint="@string/select_country"
    android:textColorHint="@color/dark_blue"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_location_city_24">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_country"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:inputType="none" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You must check the parent theme (in themes.xml file) and use a style that matches that theme. In your case, something like:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">
```

For instance, if MyApplication has the following MaterialComponents theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

Then I have to use style matching to MaterialComponents:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
```

If I try to use Material3 style

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
```

I would have a similar error.

Comment: Don't know why this wasn't marked as the correct answer yet but it's just solved my problem. Thanx.